Metal chassis grounding with wall wart supply, ESD test failed
We're building a device which takes its input power from a 12VDC wall wart PSU, and has a metal chassis. We just passed preliminary EMC/EMI test, but in the ESD test an 8kV jolt to the chassis killed the whole device. How do I fix this?
The electronics consists of two PCB's:

a mainboard which uses two SMPS's to generate the supply voltages, contains a microcontroller, quite a lot of analog circuitry and backpanel connectors (DC input jack, two MIDI connectors, seven quarter inch audio jacks, and an entirely isolated USB connector with it's own ground, connected to the rest of the circuitry via a capacitive isolator IC)
a UI-board, which connects to the mainboard via a FFC cable carrying the voltages from both of the SMPS's, ground, and a bidirectional UART signal. The UI board has buttons, LEDs, potentiometers, a display and another microcontroller.

The metal chassis is two-part, a top chassis which is the front panel, back panel and rear panel, single piece aluminum, and a bottom chassis which is a flat steel plate. The two parts do not directly connect electrically as measured by a multimeter (though they are very close, so I'm not sure that a high-voltage ESD event couldn't skip between them). The sides are plastic.
Both of the PCB's have a single uninterrupted ground plane. The chassis connects to the signal ground at three locations:

a grounding bracket at the rear panel of the unit, connected directly to the mainboard PCB ground and with a screw to the top chassis. This is located right next to the +12V DC input.
Two mounting points at the bottom of the device, connected directly to the mainboard PCB ground and with a screw to the bottom chassis. These are located relatively at the middle of the PCB, one of them approximately at a straight line from the DC connector to the SMPS's, the microcontroller and finally on to the grounding point (in case that might matter).

The UI-board has a silicone key mat on top of the buttons and LEDs, plastic caps on top of the potentiometers, and the display is covered by a plastic plate. The potentiometers are not directly electrically connected to the chassis, as measured by a multimeter.
During the ESD test, the test engineer was zapping away at an 8kV setting on the ESD gun at the silicone keypads. He repeatedly hit the metal front chassis by accident since the silicone pads are quite small, which the device withstood several times. However, suddenly the whole thing went dark after one of these zaps.
What happened? How can I fix this?
Further details:
Note that according to the standard, metal parts should be zapped only by 4kV, whereas plastic parts with 8kV, but the test engineer was complaining that it's difficult to not have the voltage jump to the panel, as was happening.
After some investigation, it turns out that the 12V wall wart was dead, i.e. no voltage output when measured with a voltmeter. Replacing that with a lab supply had the the device shorting out such that a 1A current limit the voltage would rise variously to 1.46V or 0.82V. The behaviour was the same when removing the mainboard from its case to eliminate the effect of any damage to the UI-board. Curiously, the mainboard was temporarily revived when I was touching it to see if any components got hot, showing normal current consumption at 12V (0.45A). However, after a while it stopped working again and could not be revived the same way.
Details on connectors

The connectors are isolated from the chassis: the USB-connector has a metal shell, which is separated by a small gap from the chassis, other connectors have plastic enclosures (part numbers and datasheet links UJ2-BH-W1-TH, KCDX-5S-N2, KLDX-0202-AP-LT, NRJ6HF-1)

Partial schematics
PSU input section:

Wall wart info plate:

The wall wart is a generic China sourced +12V center-positive wall wart, datasheet
From the datasheet, note that the wall wart is specified for 4kV direct discharge, and 8kV air discharge. At least the fatal zap was probably an air discharge, but it is quite possible that some of the accidental zaps might have been touches.
Device assembly
PCB sections, UI-board is located on top of Mainboard:

PCB stackup, mainboard:

Top: high speed signals, other signals, components
Inner 1: GND, only split is separate GND under (capacitively isolated) USB
Inner 2: power, planes split heavily into several different supply voltages, and some power as traces
Bottom: signals

PCB stackup, UI-board:

Top: high speed signals, other signals, components
Inner 1: GND, no splits
Inner 2: almost intact +3.3V digital power, one wide trace +3.3V analog power around the edges
Bottom: (very few) signals

Chassis assembly, simplified:

Added later
Hypothesis
I just spoke with the test engineer: in the ESD-test setup, the current is discharged through a plastic sheet under the device, to a large metal ground plane on the test table. As it happens, currently the most direct path is along the front chassis, through the grounding screw, along the ground plane on the mainboard under the SMPS and MCU, to the grounding point that connects to the bottom chassis. This does appear to rhyme with the symptoms, i.e. mainboard SMPS appears damaged (takes way too much current, even though I can't find a direct short with a multimeter when not powered on), and intermittently mystically revives only to fail again.
Potential fix:
Connect the top and bottom chassis directly without the mainboard PCB in between, to give the current another path to the bottom. Possibly even not connect the grounding points at the bottom to the PCB ground?
Feedback on the hypothesis and potential fix are welcome
Further developments:
Using a borrowed ESD gun and a makeshift test station, we ran some of our own tests, according to IEC 61000-4-2 (obviously, to our best one-day-effort, so these are not accredited laboratory results).
Importantly, whereas in the original test the engineer used a carbon fiber brush to remove accumulated charge, we used a grounding cable with bleeder resistors (as preferred by the standard), since we weren't convinced that the brush removes charge through the paint on top of the case.

The wall wart survived the test as specified in the standard, i.e. 10 times 4kV contact to the negative conductor, 10x 8kV air discharge to the plastic, occasionally jumping to the negative conductor.
A device with the fix applied via a jumper cable from top chassis to bottom chassis, and disconnecting the internal connection through the signal plane survived the test (10x 4kV contact, 8kV air discharge to all non-conducting parts (which did clearly jump to the case several times)), survived the test.
an unmodified device also survived the test.

So right now the possibility of over-testing, i.e. inadequate charge removal, is looking likely. We'll go back to the actual lab on friday, so then we'll know more.

We'd need to see some perhaps partially redacted views of the assemblies, or a simplified 3D cad drawing to understand how it's put together. Generally speaking, anything not covered by a grounding panel, like the keypad, must be designed to withstand those ESD strikes. The UI board must have a low impedance ground path to the mainboard, and also needs ESD protection on all exposed (unshielded) signals. As first step, replace the UI board with a just a ground plane, and ensure that the mainboard survives zaps to that UI groundplane. Only then other protections will make sense.

Who knows what happened. The 8kV jolt might have broken the wall wart which dumped excess supply voltage to your device. Schematics and PCB layout required I'm afraid.

In addition to diagrams as mentioned above, which connectors have metal shells or ground terminals tied with the chassis?  For example, are the phono jacks isolated or not? USB? etc.

It sounds like you're saying that if some charge wants to get from the top chassis to the bottom chassis, it has to go through the mainboard; am I understanding right?

@TannerSwett yes, that is correct

@Timo So the metal chassis, where 8kV ESD hit, is directly connected to wall wart GND?

@Justme yes. Partial schematics and general layout pictures attached.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica simplified assembly pics, partial schematics and very coarse layout added.

@TimWilliams Connector info added

What does your layout look like? I understand if you can’t dump your Gerber files, but stack-up, what layer does what, how many layers, and ground or Vcc splits?

@Timo Show the wall wart too. Do you have another/several? What happens if you simply zap the negative terminal of a working wall wart, does it also fry up? Just checking if you simply need a better wall wart and the problem is not your circuit. However, it does raise a question, if you should even bond the metal chassis to the ground plane which is directly the negative of wall wart. Is it an option to isolate the metal chassis from ground plane and wall wart negative?

@winny PCB stackup added

@Justme wall wart info plate pic added. I have a few more, but I don't have an ESD gun. That's a good question though...

Thanks. Nothing obvious. I concur with Justme, it may simply be the adapter.

@Justme added datasheet for wall wart. Isolating the chassis would surely work, however that would mean having to check EMC / EMI again and hope it still passes (we had 5.44dB of margin with the current grounding).

ESD test is the IEC 330Ω/150pF model? That should not kill the wall wart directly.

@Justme the wall wart alone survives the zapping. However, it seems that so does our device when charge is removed properly, see edits at the end of the question for more details.

Do you have more capacitance on +12 V filtered after L5301, like a lot of it?

@winny not hugely, about 25uF derated (52uF nominal) before hitting two SMPS's, one generating +-12V dual rails, and another one generating +3.3V. The rest of the rail caps are after the SMPS's.

25 uF isn’t strikingly low, but not high enough to discard the possibility of your CLC having an unfavorable resonance either. What happens if you basically sprinkle 100 nF X7R 0603 capacitors all over the board, as in solder to every Vcc pin of every IC and across every electronic cap too?

Tried to simulate it for you. Nothing obvious but I had to guess at ESL and ESR. Again, try adding X7R MLCCs across all capacitors.

@winny thanks! The problem is probably solved (see my self-answer), though a rogue resonance could cause it to be intermittent, I suppose. What do you mean by adding 100nF's? There is one at every power input pin on every IC on the board already. Add one parallel to each electrolytic? Just before the SMPS's or also after them (the latter would be a lot, this is a relatively big board)?

@Timo In general, the most EMI issues which pop up here stems from poor layout and/or lack of decoupling capacitors. If you already have capacitors for each IC very close to it, it's unlikely to help you but it's one of the first thing you can try to just add more. ESR for electrolytics is high, hence X7R in parallel.

Self-answer after repeat visit to the lab:
The device passed this time, with more punishment than before. We also had a modified unit with grounding diverted (via kludges) such that there is a path to the bottom chassis that does not need to travel under the mainboard PCB, which was connected to the chassis at a single point only. That unit also passed.
The only difference when re-testing the unmodified device was that there was a grounding cable with 2x 470k resistors connected from the exterior of the  chassis to ground, as specified by IEC 61000-4-2 for ungrounded devices. So it appears that on the first try, the grounding brush was not enough and charge accumulated.
The lesson, probably: when testing ungrounded devices, make sure the accumulated charge is really removed between shots.
